# ¿Qué me falta para completar este ejemplo de Sort Bubble en Python?

Tags: python

he estado aprendiendo Python y el método de la burbuja como manera de organizar datos en una lista, pero no logro hacerlo.

Tengo entendido que se anidan un if dentro del for, y este dentro de otro for. Pero después de ahí no tengo manera de avanzar, me encuentro con un error que me parece es básico pero no logro identificar.

Este es mi código:

```
import os
import time

print("Bienvenido al programa SORT BUBBLE")
# time.sleep(3)
os.system('cls')
num = int(input("Indica el número de valores que tendrá la lista a ordernar: "))

lista = []
a=1

for a in range(num):
    a = input(print("Dime el número: ", a))

for x in range(num):
    for b in range(num-1):
        if lista[b] > lista[b+1]:
            tempo = lista[b]
            lista[b] = lista[b+1]
            lista[b+1] = tempo

for c in num:
    print(lista[c])
```

Saben cuál es la manera más fácil de realizar esto?

Edit1:

A petición de Alvaro Vanegas, indicaré el error que me da, y es el siguiente.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Desarrollo de Software (Tecmilenio)\CARRERA\Primer Tetra\Fundamentos de programación\actividad2.py", line 17, in <module>
    if lista[b] > lista[b+1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
PS C:\Users\leoza\Desktop\Nomada Digital\Códigos y scripts\con git>
```

Comment: Sería de utilidad que compartieras el error retornado

Comment: Hola zaraterdz, aparte de la excelente respuesta de @DanteS., te quería comentar dos cosas, el último for no es necesario, **print( lista )** hace el trabajo, los for anidados básicamente están bien, es la típica implementación del algoritmo, pero el error se deriva de que usas **range( num )**, cuando debes usar **range( lista.length )**, los mismo en el interno.

Comment: @MarcePuente Gracias por el halago c: Solo vengo a aclarar, primero si querés que te imprima cada numero en una linea separada, usar un for + print es util, aunque es bueno tener en mente que print(lista) sirve. Además, si num es igual al largo de la lista, no necesitas obtener el largo de la lista. Y por ultimo, sería len(lista).

Comment: @DanteS., con la edad vienen cosas, jaja se me mezclaron los lenguajes, gracias por la corrección.

Comment: @MarcePuente de nada! No sos el unico. Estoy aprendiendo java y, más de una vez, he puesto un punto y coma en Python como si fuera Java xD

Answer (score 1):

#### La manera que se me ocurrió

Para entender el bubble sort, usé [esta pagina](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/)

Es la primera vez que escribo este algoritmo, es más, ni sabía que era. Pero lo que se me ocurrió es lo siguiente:

```
import random

# Creo una lista desordenada con numeros del 0 al 9
datos = random.sample(range(10), 10)

print("Antes:", datos)

# Esta variable indica si ocurrió un cambio de lugares hasta el momento.
# La inicializamos en True para que entre al while.
change = True

while change:
    # Si la ponemos en False, y no ocurre ningún cambio de lugar
    # change se mantendrá en False, lo que finalizará el while más adelante
    change = False
    
    for i in range(len(datos) - 1):
        if(datos[i] > datos[i + 1]):
            # El unpacking es la forma más comoda de intercambiar datos de lugar
            # Pero si se te complica, podés hacerlo como más te plasca.
            datos[i], datos[i + 1] = datos[i + 1], datos[i]

            # Cambiamos a True change, ya que hubo cambios, así continua con el while
            change = True

print("Después", datos)
```

Que produce:

```
Antes: [0, 2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 3, 7, 6, 1]
Después [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

#### Errores en tu código

A pesar de que lo resolví, te dedicaré una sección a explicarte los errores para que aprendas de ellos.

**Errores varios en la misma linea**

En esta linea: `a = input(print("Dime el número: ", a))`:

- no estás guardando el valor en la lista, solo asignandoselo a "a". Tenés que usar `lista.append` si querés agregar algo al final de una lista. Esto es la causa del error con el que te estás topando, pues crees que la lista tiene num items pero en realidad está vacía.
- El print es redundante (input ya imprime algo en pantalla). Además, como print devuelve None, te mostrará None en pantalla y el usuario tendrá que escribir pegadito a eso.
- No estás transformando el número (devuelto por input como cadena) a entero.

Esta linea debería de quedar así (además, reescribí el mensaje para que sea más claro): `lista.append(int(input(f"Dime el número en la posición {a}: ")))`

**Recorrer len(lista) veces aplicando el algoritmo no es la mejor opción**

Puede que se necesite recorrer una cantidad de veces distinta a len(lista). Para optimización y buen funcionamiento del algoritmo, es mejor usar un while como hice más arriba. De todos modos, de por sí, bubble sort es muy lento comparado con otros.

**No podés recorrer un número**

En esta linea `for c in num:` estás intentando recorrer un número. Supongo que te olvidaste poner range. Justamente range crea un objeto especial que representa un conjunto ordenado de números enteros que si puede ser recorrido.